# Showing $−1 − r^2 \leq \cos^3\theta + r^2 \cos^5\theta \leq 1 + r^2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I was studying my textbook in advanced calculus when I encountered an inequality I can't seem to justify:

> Now $−1 \leq \cos\theta \leq 1$ , which implies that
> $$−1 − r^2 \leq \cos^3\theta + r^2 \cos^5\theta \leq 1 + r^2$$

I first cubed the inequality to get
$$−1 \leq \cos^3\theta \leq 1 \tag{1}$$

Followed by adding $r^2 \cos^5 \theta$ :
$$−1 + r^2 \cos^5\theta \leq \cos^3\theta + r^2 \cos^5\theta \leq 1 + r^2 \cos^5 \theta \tag{2}$$

This is where I am stuck.  I want to remove the $\cos^5\theta$ from either sides, as well as having the left hand side contain only negative terms.

Or maybe I need to think of this inequality's justification differently?

Thank you, trig never was my strong suit.

Comment: You have to show $|\cos^3\theta + r^2 \cos^5\theta| \leq 1 + r^2$ which is true because
$$|\cos^3\theta + r^2 \cos^5\theta| \leq|\cos^3\theta| + |r^2 \cos^5\theta|\le1+r^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$-1\le \cos(t)\le 1$$

$$\implies$$

$$-1\le cos^3(t)\le 1 \tag 1$$

$$-1\le \cos^5(t)\le 1$$
and

$$-r^2\le r^2\cos^5(t)\le r^2 \tag 2$$

Now, sum $ (1) $ and $ (2)$

Comment: Makes total sense!  Clearly I need a bit more practice.  Thank you!